# Looking for identification of an electrical component

Tags: components, identification

Kind of an odd source I'm referencing, but I'm looking for the identification of an electrical part in a video game item.  Here are two pictures (screenshots of the 3d model), where I've circled the item in red...

[image: Coil and mystery item, view 1]

[image: Coil and mystery item, view 2]

The part actually looks really familiar to me, but I can't place what it is.

Keep in mind this is a virtual item in an artistically created computer game.  But that said, I believe the artists may have referenced a real item, and I'm trying to figure out what it is.

My reason to identify it is because I'm building a prop reproduction of the item - the "Rail Gun" from the Metro 2033 game.  I've got a build thread on the reproduction prop forum at http://www.therpf.com/f9/metro-2033-volt-driver-research-build-journal-167421/ if you're into that kind of thing :)

Comment: It looks like a potentiometer, but it could also be a toggle switch.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but unless they attached a fake wire to the top of the switch/pot, it's not one of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's part of a rail gun, it's very likely to be a Thyristor (Silicon Controlled Rectifier), though since there isn't an obvious gate connection, it could be a diode as well.  I'm guessing the package is TO-48 or TO-65, but it's tough to be sure.

[image]

Comment: Bingo!  I know I'd seen those before.  Now to find an old used one...

*** EDIT ***
Oh wow, check this sale -> http://www.ebay.com/itm/RUSSIAN-USSR-KU201L-THYRISTOR-VINTAGE-NEW-1985-YEAR-/110998236648

Comment: Looks like you found an exact match!

Comment: Indeed - order placed from a different seller in Lithuania.  4 of them for $5 (with shipping).  Thanks much for the lead!